# Safe publication for a singleton using local vars

Tags: java, multithreading

While going through this [article](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#:%7E:text=Safe%20DCL%20is%20slower%20because,at%20the%20end%20of%20constructor.) I came across the below code which explained safe publication fields.

```
public class SafeLocalDCLFactory implements Factory {
  private volatile Singleton instance;

  @Override
  public Singleton getInstance() {
    Singleton res = instance;
    if (res == null) {
      synchronized (this) {
        res = instance;
        if (res == null) {
          res = new Singleton();
          instance = res;
        }
      }
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

My doubt is why do we need local var `res` defined in the `getInstance()`? Isn't the `volatile` and `DCL` enough to guarantee `safe publication`? What exactly is the purpose of defining a local var `res` here and then comparing it for `null`?

EDIT : The article explains the below to justify the need to use local var. But how are we protecting ourselves from returning null?

> The introduction of local variable here is a correctness fix, but only
> partial: there still no happens-before between publishing the
> Singleton instance, and reading of any of its fields. We are only
> protecting ourselves from returning "null" instead of Singleton
> instance

Answer (score 1):

It minimizes the number of reads from the volatile variable `instance`. Volatile variable access is more expensive than non-volatile memory access, because usually it involves a memory barrier. By assigning it to a temporary variable, this code reads from the volatile variable only once if it is already initialized, instead of twice (once to check, once to return).

Comment: F-Up question: as only the code within the null check to create the instance is synchronized, wouldn't it be possible for `instance` to change inbetween the null check and creating the instance? Scenario: null check positive ; thread change ; null check positive ; do synchronized block and create & save isntance ; thread change ; do synchronized block again and override existing instance

Comment: Once one thread gets into the synchronized block, another thread cannot get in. When the initializing thread completes, waiting threads will check again and see that instance is already initialized.

Comment: @JohannesH.in the 2nd thread change won't it again check for the null inside the sync block? There it will be false since already created by 1st thread?

Comment: I... missed the second check. yes, you guys are correct.

Comment: @BurakSerdar, Thanks but in the article its mentioned the real reason for using local var is below : "The introduction of local variable here is a correctness fix, but only partial: there still no happens-before between publishing the Singleton instance, and reading of any of its fields. We are only protecting ourselves from returning "null" instead of Singleton instance." How are we protecting ourselves from returning null using local var?

Comment: @ghostrider Is the article older than Java 5? Java versions before  5 did not give a "Happens-before" guarantee, as statements could be re-ordered even if variables were declared volatile. Ever sice java 5, such guaratnee exists however, so I do not quite get why the article claims there's not.

Comment: @JohannesH.the article states volatile does provide happens-before guarantee, and hence they are using it in the code above. I am just curious why they are using local var. The reasoning they said is, it protects ourselves from returning null instead of singleton instance. Not sure how that's possible

Comment: This article disagrees with the assertion that volatile does not provide happened-before: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html#the-java-volatile-happens-before-guarantee

Comment: They also say "there still no happens-before between publishing the Singleton instance, and reading of any of its fields", which doesn't make sense to me either if they recognize the existence of this very happens-before guarantee.

Comment: Based on the Jenkov article: "The reads / writes before a write to a volatile variable are guaranteed to "happen before" the write to the volatile variable. ". So @JohannesH. that statement does not make sense.

Comment: @BurakSerdar, what do you think about the reasoinng mentioned in the article to justify the use of local vars? "We are only protecting ourselves from returning "null" instead of Singleton instance". Any idea how are we protecting ourselves using local vars?

Comment: I do not understand that sentence.